# How to get sim card setting in android Programatically

Tags: android, dual-sim

I have a device with dual-sim card. Is there anyway to get the sim info what is using to make a call in android programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

you may try this link

SIm  Enable/Disable 3G programmatically

http://life-optimized.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-enabledisable-3g.html